# Ping ERR - Ruby on Rails (https://api-iam.intercom.io/messenger/web/ping)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BswWS.png)

https://api-iam.intercom.io/messenger/web/ping - {"type":"error.list","request_id":"0000g139l0knoips3sf0","errors":[{"code":"client_error","message":"An app_id parameter must be specified"}]}

I am getting a `403 Response` on POST method in Ruby as backend and Ruby on Rails as a front-end

Comment: Please provide a relevant code snippet, otherwise we can't help you. Besides that: The error states you haven't provided an `app_id`, so that is probably the issue.